# Javascript: Playing multiple AudioSourceNodes simultaneously via one AudioContext garbles audio output

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api, audiocontext

I have a typescript class that can playback 8-bit, 11025 Hz, mono PCM streams. When one sound is playing and the second one is started, it garbles up all playback until only one sound is being played again. There is one `AudioContext` and every Sound-class creates their own buffers and source nodes when playback starts.

Simple pseudo example of my set-up:

```js
const context = new AudioContext();
const data    = new Float32Array(); // <- Imagine this being filled with data.

function play() {
    const buffer = context.createBuffer(1, data.length, 11025);
    buffer.copyToChannel(buffer, 0);

    const srcNode = context.createBufferSource();
    srcNode.buffer = buffer;
    srcNode.connect(context.destination);

    srcNode.start(); 
}
```

Imagine the audio being played is 2 seconds long. When invoking `play()` for the first time, it just plays fine. If you wait until it finished playing and invoke it a second time, it plays just fine.

The issues start when invoking `play()` *while* a previously started AudioSourceNode is *still playing*. It almost looks like both sources are fighting for the same resources.

I've tried putting gain and panning nodes in between the source nodes and context, but nothing seems to help. Creating a multitude of `AudioContext` objects shouldn't be a solution either due to performance/resource limitations.

**Why can't two (different) sounds being played back *at the same time*?**

I'm completely clueless why this is a problem. Thanks in advance!

#edit1: It seems like when using a `gainNode` and setting its value to `0.5`, I can play two sounds simultaneously without playing becoming garbled. It seems that audio is being added *on top* of currently playing audio data. How do we mix this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. For anyone having similar issues: The answer is using a `DynamicsCompressorNode` and use that to route all audio source nodes to.

```js
const context = new AudioContext();
const compressorNode = context.createDynamicsCompressor();

compressorNode.connect(context.destination); // <- Connect to AudioContext

function play() {
    const buffer = context.createBuffer(1, data.length, 11025);
    buffer.copyToChannel(buffer, 0);

    const srcNode = context.createBufferSource();
    srcNode.buffer = buffer;
    srcNode.connect(compressor); // <- Connect to DynamicsCompressorNode

    srcNode.start(); 
}
```